Oracle Autonomous DB suddenly Not Found
I am developing a game using Oracle Autonomous database as a cloud database. I use Oracle SODA to access the json documents. All worked well until a few days ago when I suddenly got 404 and database not found.
I assumed that I had changed something and went back to a test I had done a few days earlier so I was sure I hade the correct code but still get the same error.
I checked the database if something happened to the tables but they are still there.
As I get the same message when collecting the access token I continued testing with  that piece of code from the "old" code that I know I have not changed and get the same result.
Here is a short summary:

Access to the database suddenly got 404

Tested with code I hade not touched since it worked and got the same problem

Checked and queried the database to check that the tables was in place

Tested cURL from the Oracle view that failed
curl -X POST "https://Gxxxxxxxxxx-zzz.adb.eu-stockholm-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/mmm/oauth/token" 
-H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n 'xxxxxx..:yyyyy..' | base64)" 
-H "Accept: application/json" 
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
{
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "Not Found",
"type": "tag:oracle.com,2020:error/NotFound",
"instance": "tag:oracle.com,2020:ecid/b2ea7658965bf0e7a96129da6f615cd6"


Copied directly from the Oracle Cloud Console:

https://g24030c24944819-zzz.adb.eu-stockholm-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/

I am lost and really need and appreciate some ideas how move forward with this.

Here you can list your ADB's from the cli. This is what I do first when my DEMODB is stopped due to not being used for 7 days (Always Free eligible). I just have to start it again.
cat list-autonomous-databases.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

oci db autonomous-database list \
  --compartment-id $C \
  --output table \
  --query 'data [*].{Version:"db-version",DBName:"db-name",id:id,Status:"lifecycle-state",DBWorkoad:"db-workload"}'



./list-autonomous-databases.sh
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DBName | DBWorkoad | Status    | Version | id                                                                                                       |
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEMODB | OLTP      | AVAILABLE | 23ai    | ocid1.autonomousdatabase.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.xxxxxxxxxxx |
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

cat start-autonomous-databases.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

oci db autonomous-database start \
  --autonomous-database-id "${1:-$DB_OCID}"

Best of luck!

Thanks Bjarte, I am doing the same. The tables exists but I cannot access them.
